# How to see what Play! thinks the database schema is

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am writing a Play! Framework backend. I started out setting `jpa.ddl=update`. However, as I was advised by everyone, I changed this when preparing for production to `jpa.ddl=none`.

Since doing that, it has been my understanding that I have to keep track of the database schema myself by using database evolutions. I have been fine doing this so far, but now that I am making modifications to my models, I'm finding that JPA is executing SQL queries assuming certain tables exist that I have not manually created.

I can't imagine the right thing to do is simply run my code, receive an error like this:

```
ERROR: relation "games_users" does not exist
```

and then write the evolution script that will create that table. So is there a way to see what JPA/Play thinks the current schema should be based on my model so I can create it or is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be, using `jpa.ddl=update` while you're in development, and you keep modifying your JPA models. Let JPA update your model is not recommended in production, but you can use it in development. When your software is stable, and you don't need to modify your JPA entities anymore you can do the switch from the autogenerated schema to the fixed schema.

Another solution could be develop on another database name and then make a diff beetween the two databases generating a `sql` script.

A more boring solution, would be manually keeping the `SQL` evolution script, writing a script everytime you modify the JPA entities.

Comment: This is a solution but if this is the "right" solution then it seems this is a downside to using play. Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the whole point of using Hibernate/JPA to abstract away from the SQL?